# Database call by FillbyCustomerId in Datagridview2

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, foreign-keys

I created a database and dataset1, in this database are 2 tables, customertable and visits table, in the visit table is a foreign key called CustomerID that has relationship with Customertable/ID Column,That means that everycustomer can have multiple visits, know I created a query in dataset1.xsd VisitsTable and I named it FillbyCustomerID and GetbyCustomerID but now I don't know how to call these records on datagridview2, example must show all visits of customer1 example.

This is the VisitTableAdapter code

```
Me.VisitTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Customer)
```

I have tried

```
Me.VisitTableAdapter.FillbyCustomerID(Me.DataSet1.Visits)
```

but it doesn't work, I need to call all visits of 1 customer.

Comment: Your FillByCustomerID query will (or ought to) take a parameter specifying the id. You need to pass this parameter in the call in your second line of code.

Comment: Aha can u show me that code my friend

Comment: I told you elsewhere to add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL for that method to filter by `CustomerId`. If there's no parameter on that method then you obviously haven't done that. If you don't follow instructions then don't be surprised that it doesn't work.  What does the SQL for that query look like?  By the way, how can you be passing the `Customer` `DataTable` to the `Fill` method and the `Visitors` `DataTable` to the `FillByCustomerId` method? That makes no sense. You really should have done some relevant reading by now like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx).

Comment: Yess i added this to queery but know i do not know how to call this in the gridview do u understand,

Comment: SELECT        ID, Termin, CustomerID  FROM            Termin   WHERE        (CustomerID = @Id)